# adding object with association to cart

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on an eCommerce store and essentially I have a product that can have many attributes, that range from size to color.

Now currently I'm able to allow the user to add an item to their cart. By doing this:

```
<%= button_to 'Legg til', line_items_path(product_id: @product), remote: true %>
```

and my `line_items_controller` create action looks like this:

```
  def create
    product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
    @line_item = @cart.add_product(product.id)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @line_item.save
        format.html { redirect_to store_url(product.store), notice: 'Line item was successfully created.' }
        format.js { @current_item = @line_item }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @line_item }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @line_item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

and the `add_product`method on the Cart model looks like this:

```
  def add_product(product_id)
    current_item = line_items.find_by(product_id: product_id)
    if current_item
      current_item.quantity += 1
    else
      current_item = line_items.build(product_id: product_id)
    end
    current_item
  end
```

now this works well, however I'd like for the user to be able to choose between different attributes. My `line_item` currently stores `product_id` and `cart_id`, and because there could be several attributes to one product, I've gone ahead and created a new model, called `line_item_attributes` which looks like this:

```
class LineItemAttribute < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :line_item
  belongs_to :product_attribute
end
```

now I'm able to display the form with the different product attributes:

```
    <%= simple_form_for @line_item do |f| %>        
      <% @attribute_categories.each do |category| %>

        <%= f.simple_fields_for :line_item_attributes do |attributes_form| %>
          <%= attributes_form.association :product_attribute, collection: category.product_attributes, label: category.name %>
        <% end %>

      <% end %>

    <% end %>
```

and my controller action for that looks like this:

```
  def new
    @product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
    @attribute_categories = @product.attribute_categories
    @line_item = LineItem.new
    @line_item.line_item_attributes.build
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
```

and my `new.js.erb` essentially displays the modal containing the form:

```
$('body').append("<%= escape_javascript render('line_items/new_modal') %>");
$('#product-modal').modal('show');
```

now I'm wondering, how can I rewrite the `add_product` method to also save the nested attributes that is specified, so I can create them.